# Android soft keyboard adjustPan adjust views further up

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an activity that looks like this:

[image]

I've setup the activity to include adjustPan for the EditTexts

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

Because of this, when the "Driver" EditText has focus, the activity looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the window to pan even further to show the "Password" EditText and Button above the soft keyboard when the "Driver" EditText has focus. Like this:

[image]

Is this possible? I'd like to avoid adjustResize if at all possible.
Any input helps, Thanks.